# Can't change workspace on i3wm

Tags: window-manager, i3, tiling-wm

I'm having this problem with i3 for the first time: I can't change workspace with mod+*number of workspace*. Neither I can move programs to other workspaces.

The only thing I could think of that can be a problem is that I am using a laptop with its lid closed, connected to a monitor.

Do you have any ideas of what could be the problem?

EDIT:
I was actually trying to fix the problem and I found out that i3 doesn't change workspace because of the fact I put roman numbers instead of regular arabic ones. Why is this happening? I doesn't work only when I put:

```
set $ws1 "I"
```

If do this, once restarted, i3 will show me the "I" character in the first workspace, but if I try to change workspace to 2 and then get back to the first one which has a roman number, it will refuse to get back to it. Why is this happening?

Comment: I installed i3 over Ubuntu’s gnome, so everything concerning graphics is currently working fine. I just edited the post, please check that out because the problem is not the lid actually. Thanks for you reply anyway. If you have suggestions about what I added, please tell me because I can’t figure out why this is happening. Thanks again.

Comment: Why won't use arabic numbers if I may ask?

Comment: I just like roman numbers more. I think they are better for styling workspace numbers :). So is there a way to fix it?